# DIfficulty to reference an id i sent within a hidden field

Tags: php, html

Below is the code

```
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="ID" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id; ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"/></td>                            </tr>
```

Here is the line I referenced it but it seems not to work. Can someone help, please.
$id = $_POST['id'];

Comment: sidenote: `id != ID`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're dealing with an issue of case sensitivity.

On your input you have...

```
<input name="ID" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id; ?>"/>
```

but you have...

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

on your receiving page.

Try changing your form to...

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id; ?>"/>
```

Notice the lowercase "id" in the name. A good way to test yourself is on your receiving page you can always do this first thing temporarily.

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
    exit;
?>
```

This will print your entire POST array so you can see if you are in fact sending the data you expect. If you are, then you know you have an issue with the way you are "using" that data.